# How do i fix "Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' "?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, adt, eclipse-adt

I installed ADT by [Andmore](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore). When i booted Eclipse, this error happen:

> Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

I think i have to fix this error. How do i fix this error?

## My efforts

- I looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34484462/6366398).
- I searched on Google.
  Keyword: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

but it wasn't fixed.

[Multiposted](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31085/15185)(Japanese)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot to add the environment variable. It was fixed after i added the environment variable.

## Windows

### Windows10

1. Log in as Administrator
2. Right click Windows icon, and click "System".
3. Click advanced Setting
4. Click written environment variable button.
5. Click variable what named Path and edit.
6. Click written "new" and enter platform-tools' path
7. Click OK.

### Windows7

1. Click start, right click "computer", and open the advanced option
2. Click written environment variable button.
3. In system environment variable, click line what named `Path`, and edit.
4. In variable, add platform-tools' path. Do ***NOT*** delete entered variable!
5. Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the eclipse, Before that open task manager> Processes end adb process
Open eclipse 
the error is not there

Answer (score 1):

In **Windows 7/10**

System Properties-> Advanced(Tab) -> Environment variables -> Edit **path** in System variables
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools